# This link may be harmful blue screen through sendinblue emailing

Tags: email, security, sendinblue, browser-security

I recently launched an emailing campaign with Brevo (ex sendinblue) to about 200 people (zero bounce, all good contacts).
After a few hours, the links from this email were all blocked: whenever you'd try to open the message in the browser view or would click on the call to action, the blue screen saying the link may be harmful would show up.
[image: blue screen showing an alert message that read This link may be harmfull. We have found suspicious activities for this link.]
Several recipients complained about it. While it was working during tests for me, I could confirm it got soon blocked as well. I tried from my desktop / mobile / on multiple browsers with the same result and thought the issue was on the emailing platform side.
Clicking on "visiting the unsafe site" would not do anything, the bluescreen remained.
Their support kept saying they were not seeing any problem and were anything but helpful. I am trying to understand what happened, and figure out if I should change provider.
Anyone faced similar issue or knows why this happened?

Comment: I am not sure why the question was voted as unclear or not showing research efforts... I am grateful for any hint on that matter to understand what is happening (or question that might help the thinking). I researched similar screens on google / google images etc and got nowhere. Since I am having the same exact one on which ever browser I test with, I am not able to wrap my head around it. Where does the message come from... it is not from the browser so who is generating it? The link on visiting anyway does not yield any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after multiple back/forth emails with support, insisting on them testing with the link I used in a campaign I got the answer that makes sense: apparently email campaigns generate individual links and if one of those links is accessed more than 7 times, they block it considering it's suspicious activity.
So that blue screen is generated on their side.
If you want to share on social media or via your personal network the link to the mirror view of the campaign, you have to set up a "share with social" campaign to avoid that.
It would be a good thing to mention on their documentation :S
I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it seems I've fixed it now.

Essentially I looked through all my Brevo profile settings and campaign settings. I think it was something to do with some new link type. Sorry I don't have more info - I've looked through my account again and can't find the setting, but it may have only been visible temporarily.